# Proper way to call a REST service in Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I've taken an AngularJS web page that is able to call my REST service using GET, and put this code into my Android/Phonegap project and the rest service isn't called.

so this code below works standalone but not within phone application

```
$http.get('http://localhost:40884/api/sampleapi/get').success(function (data) {
    alert("cool");
    $scope.posts = data;
    $scope.loading = false;
})
    .error(function (request, status, error) {
        alert("err");
        console.log(data);
        $scope.error = "An Error has occured while loading posts!";
        $scope.loading = false;
    });
```

I've checked the manifest has

and the res/config.xml file has

```
    <access origin="*"/> <!-- allow local pages -->
```

But these haven't made a difference. Trying to trace out the request,status,error variables only retrieve a 0 for the error variable.

Any ideas about what to try here appreciated

Cheers

M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe `localhost` is your computer, and since your phone or emulator is a different machine, you need to replace `localhost` with your computer's local ip address(something like 192.168.1.10). Later when you want to make it work even on different networks you need to put your api online(like a hosting)

I suggest that you assign a static local ip to your computer and use that address instead of localhost all the time.